# Масштабирование элементов в окне с помощью колесика мыши

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview, wheelevent

Как с помощью колесика мышки изменять размеры фигур, которые имеются в окне приложения?

Для примера я взял несколько фигур. Есть идея: в функцию прокрутки колесика добавить коэффициент, который будет увеличивать/уменьшать элементы окна. Не сильно похоже на правду?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


ded = [
    [(140, 140), (570, 525)],
    [(20, 20), (350, 525), (100, 300), (20, 20)],
    [(50, 50), (280, 175), (150, 240)],
    [(80, 80), (210, 225), (300, 300), (340, 40)],
    [(510, 110), (340, 275), (490, 390), (510, 110)]]


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.setGeometry(680, 400, 700, 550)
        self.setWindowTitle('Das')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawLine(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawLine(self, qp):
        path = QPainterPath()

        def draw_trajectory(line):
            for i, (x, y) in enumerate(line):
                if i == 0:
                    path.moveTo(x, y)
                else:
                    path.lineTo(x, y)

        for line in ded:
            draw_trajectory(line)
            qp.drawPath(path)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from random import randint

ded = [
    [(140, 140), (570, 525)],
    [(20, 20), (350, 525), (100, 300), (20, 20)],
    [(50, 50), (280, 175), (150, 240)],
    [(80, 80), (210, 225), (300, 300), (340, 40)],
    [(510, 110), (340, 275), (490, 390), (510, 110)]]


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):                                    # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.resize(1000, 600)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        """ Увеличение или уменьшение масштаба. """
        zoomInFactor = 1.25
        zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor

        # Save the scene pos
        oldPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        # Zoom
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            zoomFactor = zoomInFactor
        else:
            zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor
        self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)

        # Get the new position
        newPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        # Move scene to old position
        delta = newPos - oldPos
        self.translate(delta.x(), delta.y())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

        self.w = GraphicsView(self)                                       # +++
        self.drawLine()                                                   # +++

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 200))
        self.resize(1000, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Das')

#    def paintEvent(self, e):
#        qp = QPainter()
#        qp.begin(self)
#        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
#        self.drawLine(qp)
#        qp.end()

    def drawLine(self, qp=None):                    # + =None
        path = QPainterPath()
        def draw_trajectory(line):
            for i, (x, y) in enumerate(line):
                if i == 0:
                    path.moveTo(x, y)
                else:
                    path.lineTo(x, y)

        for line in ded:
            draw_trajectory(line)

#            qp.drawPath(path)

            self.w.scene().addPath(                                        # +++
                path, 
                QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230)),
                QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(*[randint(0, 255) for _ in range(4)]))   
                )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ShevIv использование для этих целей  QGraphicsView и QGraphicsScene это самый простой и правильный вариант. Если мой ответ помог вам, не забывайте отметить его как полезный.